# I want my printer to have an email address

Tags: email, printing

Here's what I need: have my printer automatically print all emails coming to a specific address. This way, a forward to this address will have it printed. Including attached documents of course.

What is the best way to do it?

Opening a mail account/some polling application solution comes to mind. Ideas will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In Microsoft Outlook you can create a rule that will print every email when it is received.

Mozilla Thunderbird can do it [with an add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/autoprint2/).

Answer (score 1):

Many [MTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent)s allow you to specify a program to be run when an email is received at a specific address. Simply have the program run decode all attachments and print everything out.

Comment: Your answer is not exactly clear.

Comment: @iglvzx: The question is no better.

Comment: I've submitted an edit to clarify what an MTA is. I linked to the Wikipedia article on message transfer agents.